# Detach an image from a page using php

Tags: attachments

I want to detach/unattach an image from the page it's currently attached to -- by using PHP, instead of the "Detach" link in the Media Library.

I found this (in /wp-admin/includes/media.php#3164):

```
$result = $wpdb->query( "UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_parent = 0 WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND ID IN ( $ids_string )" );
```

So I assume I could just use this in my own PHP, replacing the `$ids_string` with the ID of the attachment to remove.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no core (4.8.1) functions like `detach_post()` or `wp_update_attachment()` but we can use [`wp_update_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/) to detach attachments:

```
$result = wp_update_post( [
    'ID'          => $attachment_id,
    'post_parent' => 0,               // detach
] );  

if( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
    // error
} else {
    // success
}
```

We can also create a helper function (untested):

```
/**
 * WPSE-279554: Detach Post
 *
 * @param int   $post_id Post ID
 * @return bool $return If post was successfully detached
 */
function wpse_detach_post( $post_id )
{
    // Validate input - we only want positive integers
    if( ! is_int( $post_id ) || $post_id < 1 ) 
        return false;

    $result = wp_update_post( [
        'ID'          => $post_id,
        'post_parent' => 0,              // detach
    ] ); 

    return ! is_wp_error( $result );
}
```

Usage Example:

```
if( wpse_detach_post( $post_id ) ) {
    // success
} else {
    // error
}
```